# TFS workspace with a new user account with same user ID

Tags: version-control, tfs, dynamics-ax-2012, tfvc

My user account was removed, but I still needed it. So a new user account was created with the same ID and a different display name.

When I open Dynamics AX 2012, I always receive the message that a workspace is already used by my old user account:

> The working folder is already in use by old_user workspace_xxx.

So I can't use TFS version control.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by giving the old workspace a new owner, my new user account, with the following command:

```
 tf workspace /collection:http://tfs.yourtfslink.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
      yourWorkSpace;"old_user" /newowner:"new_user"
```